# Telethon How to read channel?

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

for i in client.get_message_history(-1001149594247)[1]:
    print(i)

ValueError: Could not find the input entity corresponding to "PeerUser(user_id=-1001149594247)".Make sure you have encountered this peer before.

How to fix? Or what other methods are there for reading channels in a telegram using a python

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you put more code, and what you intend/expect `-1001149594247` to be? Should `PeerUser(user_id=-1001149594247)` correspond to an object you want to access?

Comment: I would like to get messages from private channel Telegram

It works with some channels, but that channel - error

What parameters should I push in `get_message_history`?

Code:
```
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel

from_id = -1001149594247

for i in client.get_message_history(PeerChannel(channel_id=from_id))[1]:

    ...
`

Error:

    'Make sure you have encountered this peer before.'.format(peer)

ValueError: Could not find the input entity corresponding to "PeerChannel(channel_id=-1001149594247)".Make sure you have encountered this peer before.

Comment: try `client.get_message_history(client.get_entity(-1001149594247))` or `client.get_message_history(client.get_input_entity(-1001149594247))`

Comment: @AlexeyPoloz Did you solve it?